# Extracting XML contents from xmltype

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I am getting the error "ORA-00911: invalid character" while using the following SQL query through OCI

SELECT EXTRACT(FTAG, 'ptag').GETCLOBVAL() FROM SAMPLECS WHERE INDEXID=1;

This query works well with SQLPlus.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: "using the ... query through OCI" - how exactly; have you included the statement-terminating semicolon in the OCI call? It would be helpful to show the actual cdoe you're using to execute this.

Comment: Alex, thanks much, you made me to blink my eyes and I have passed through this.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute an SQL statement through OCI (or JDBC, or other places) it should not have a trailing semicolon.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(FTAG, 'ptag').GETCLOBVAL() FROM SAMPLECS WHERE INDEXID=1
```

The semicolon is a statement separator, not part of the statement itself. It is used by SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, Toad and other clients to allow several statements to be run together, and delimits each individual statement.

SQL Fiddle lets you choose the separator which is useful when you have any PL/SQL code in your schema build. So do other clients, but less obviously. In SQL*Plus you can use `set sqlterminator` to change for the default semicolon to something else. I'm not sure you'd ever have any reason to, unless perhaps you were given a script to run that used a different character already for some reason.

Comment: Semicolon at the end is by mistake.  I got it once I have gone through your reply.  And these info are very useful.  Thanks much.

Comment: @SenthilKumarMathivanan - yes, I was just formalising what the earlier comment had hinted at, as an answer (since this is a Q&A site!), and to keep things tidy.